# Старуха Изергиль

Tags: литература, ономастика

Конечно, это произведение Горького знают все. Но мне всегда было интересно, а что это, собственно, за имя такое? Или это не имя, а фамилия? Или вообще прозвище?
Вообще, это реальное имя или Горький просто придумал его? Собственно, если проводить аналогию с Данко, то такое имя есть. По крайней мере, есть романс "Данко", который поется на мотив одного из Венгерских танцев Брамса. А как же с Изергиль?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть несколько версий.
 Возможно, Изергиль - имя романтической героини -  это первая часть аккерманского топонима Исерлия (название села), а вторая часть - имя героини легенды Мамина-Сибиряка «Слезы царицы» Кара-Нингиль.

2 вариант: фонетически Изергиль близко слову игграззиль (варианты: иггдразиль, иггдрасиль), являясь, по существу, анаграммой. Так назывался у древних скандинавов гигантский ясень, являющийся структурной основой мира, древо жизни и судьбы — аналог библейского древа познания добра и зла. Три корня Иггдразиля простирались в царство мертвых, к великанам (или богам) и людям. Возникающая ассоциация подчеркнута и тем, что слушателю легенд старухи кажется, что «ее скрипучий голос звучал так, как будто это роптали все забытые века, воплотившись в ее груди тенями воспоминаний». Изергиль стремится передать слушателю мудрость прежних поколений, истинное знание о жизни. В сущности, она выполняет роль посредника между прошлым и будущим, идеалом и реальностью, памятью и мечтой, вечным и сиюминутным. Как вечнозеленое древо жизни, Иггдразиль был пропитан священным медом поэзии. А ведь именно красота сказок Изергиль, их поэтичность привлекают слушателя в первую очередь. О роли красоты в мире размышляет и сама рассказчица.

Answer (score 4):

Изергиль (Иезекииль, Й’хезкэль) – женское имя, произошло от древнееврейского и переводится как "Бог сделает сильной". Имя мужское, по крайней мере, изначально, если отталкиваться от библейского текста.

Comment: А элементарное совпадение вы исключаете?
С чего бы Горькому делать героиню еврейкой?

Comment: Если имя древнееврейского происхождения, то это не значит, что его носитель — еврей. У нас полстраны Иванов, на минуточку. Тем более Иезекииль — это один из самых известных пророков.

Comment: Если имя древнееврейского происхождения, то это разумеется ничего не значит.
Но если это имя чисто древнееврейское - и нигде больше не используется, то это как раз "значит". И очень много.

Comment: @behemothus ничего это не значит. Отсылка к Библии куда вероятней, чем необходимость подчеркнуть происхождение персонажа. Произведение "Старуха Изергиль" само по себе мистико-философское, так что употребление столь необычного имени не может быть случайностью.

Comment: >ничего это не значит. Отсылка к Библии куда вероятней,  
  
Как понимать прикажете? Отсылка к библии - "ничего не значит"? Да еще к мужскому имени?

Comment: Ничего не значит то, что это еврейское имя (это к тому, что Горький не делает героиню еврейкой, а просто использует имя для аллюзии). Существенна только отсылка к Библии. Тут нужно искать параллели с образом Иезекииля, чтобы понять смысловую нагрузку.

Answer (score 2):

Прав **Третий глаз**, указавающий, что ИЗЕРГИЛЬ это еврейское имя. Но он ошибочно производит его от *Иезекииль*, *Й’хезкэль*. Здесь другое еврейское имя, типа Йезер/+г(=ий)+иль.

Ниже я поместил скриншот из Электронной книги памяти воинов-евреев (графа Мемориал) по фамилии *Езерский*, - [ЭКПВЕ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbviz.png).

Буква **Г** может встать на место **Й** вместо окончания -ий (*Иезерий*) так же, как в итальянском языке все библейские имена, начинающиеся на *Йе*/*Йа*/*Йо*/*Йу*, пишутся с начальной **G** : *Geronimo*, *Giacomo*, *Giordano*, *Giovanni*, *Giovanni*, *Giacobbe*, *Gisella* и др.

Но прав и **behemothus**, пишущий:

> Я все более и более склоняюсь к идее, что это реальное имя, цыганского или молдавского (оно же - румынское) происхождения... реальное имя, позаимствованное Горьким для его героини, могло быть любого цыганского происхождения. Это представляется самым правдоподобным.

А сейчас я объясню, почему правы оба, каждый со своей стороны. Вот, у меня в руках книжка - *Татьяна Соколова. "Тайны российских цыган." Изд.АСТ,2001 г.*. Книжка написана по беседам с потомственной цыганкой, профессиональной московской гадалкой Алмазой. На стр.11-12 можно прочитать (я цитирую) :

> ... однако[цыгане] всегда обижались, если слышали малейший намек на своё участие в преследовании евреев. Естественно, ничего обиднее быть не может, поскольку самих цыган всегда и отовсюду гнали, и к вечно скитающимся по свету евреям они относились с сочувствием. Считается, что у цыган и евреев много общего. О том, как относятся к цыганам евреи, доподлинно неизвестно, однако то, что у цыган смешанные браки разрешаются только с евреями, знают все.

Могу добавить к этому, что цыгане, как и евреи, делятся на 12 племён (хотя это деление уже практически стёрлось), и, что я лично сталкивался с цыганами, носившими характерные еврейские имена, типа Соломон, Моисей, Яков... Поэтому еврейское имя у цыганской старухи явление вполне реальное. В образе старухи Изергиль А.М.Горький изобразил мудрую старую цыганку, а еврейско-цыганское имя для неё у самих же цыган и позаимствовал.

[image: Езерский]

Answer (score 2):

Основоположник современной нейрохирурги носит фамилию Yasargil. По происхождению он турок. Памятуя связь старухи с неким турком, можно предположить, что эта фамилия заимствована от него. Разница в произношении Яшаргиль и Изергиль представляется несущественной: писали же раньше не Джексон, а Жаксон.

Answer (score 1):

Я все более и более склоняюсь к идее, что это реальное имя, цыганского или молдавского (оно же - румынское) происхождения. 
Все иные версии (ну разве топонимическая) представляются очень натянутыми. 
Ну какие скандинавы или евреи в колоритной фольклорной (едва ли сказочной) истории?
Еврейская очень странна еще и в силу странной фонетики.  В собственном псевдониме - Иегудиил Хламида - имя предполагаемого ангела (архангела?) Горький передал фонетику совершенно по-другому. К тому же значение - "славящий Бога" (абсолютно не оправдана попытка перевести как "бог - еврей"). Зачем такое имя цыганской старухе - да еще с таким славным прошлым?

К сожалению, дальше этого предположения я не сдвинулся. С румынским у меня никак, а с цыганскими еще хуже. Но все-таки выскажу соображения, путь и тупиковые по обеим версиям.
Румынская - окончание "иль" может быть вариантом общероманского -ель: Мирабель, Изабель  и проч., а вот с первой частью совсем туго.
Для цыганской (романи) фонетики тоже, имхо, как-то нехарактерно, но язык бессарабских цыган мог - это суржик сразу нескольких диалектных цыганских групп (балканской, влашской, центральной и даже северной - см. карту в википедии), достаточно сильно отличающихся по фонетике. Так что реальное имя, позаимствованное Горьким для его героини, могло быть любого цыганского происхождения. Это представляется самым правдоподобным. 
Пока все.

Comment:  Не вижу оснований для такой версии. Окончания "иль/эль" есть во многих именах древнееврейского происхождения, тем более "иль" как раз намекает на русскую ("православную", "греческую") трактовку имени, сравните пары "Михаил — Михаэль", "Гавриил — Габриэль", "Даниил — Даниэль".